# Mask in Crystal Report field

Tags: crystal-reports

Here in Brasil we have a number named CNPJ with this mask 00.000.000/0000-00, i save this number in SQL like an int column, when i make my reports works fine, so, the fiels appears
   00000000000000
how i put like a mask on the field in the report to show like this
                            00.000.000/0000-00

Thanks by any orientation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're NOT going to need leading zeros then:

```
local stringvar sample := totext({table.number},0,'');
if length(sample)<>14 then "Handle the error case" else
  picture(sample,"xx.xxx.xxx/xxxx-xx")
```

otherwise, add the leading zeros in:

```
local stringvar sample := totext({table.number},"00000000000000");
picture(sample,"xx.xxx.xxx/xxxx-xx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Must add a Formula Field with this formula
mid({imprimePJ;1.doc_cnpj},1,2)+"."+ mid({imprimePJ;1.doc_cnpj},3,3)+"."+ mid({imprimePJ;1.doc_cnpj},6,3)+"/"+
 mid({imprimePJ;1.doc_cnpj},9,4)+"-"+mid({imprimePJ;1.doc_cnpj},13,2)